# Refresh <a> that has PHP variable connected to XML URL without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have two files home.php and calc.php, the file calc.php has variables parsing from XML URL and this url data keep changing automatically but the problem is i need a specific element in this home.php keep refreshing automatically 
as you see in my code there is a div has alink inside it and the link has php variable $amount and this var keep updating,
so i tried to use AJAX like this but it did not work and after 1 s the link disapear So what to do please? 
THANKS

```js
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function () {
    $('#low2z3').load('calc.php'});
}, 1000);
```

```html
 <div  id="linnnez4" class="linnne res1"><a id="low2z3"><?php echo $amount1;?></a> </div>
 
 
 
 <!--in calc.php-->
 <?php
 $url = 'http://magneticexchange.com/export.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach($xml->item as $item) {
if($item->from == "PRUSD" && $item->to == "NTLRUSD") {
  $give = $item->in;
  $get = $item->out;
  $amount = 10;
  $give1 = $amount." ".$item->from;
  $get1 =  $amount * $get / $give;
  $get2 =  number_format($get1, 2). " ".$item->to;
  $amount1 = $item->amount;

  break;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: jQuery's `.load()` function *replaces* the HTML in the target element with whatever you got from the AJAX call. So your `calc.php` needs to output the new contents (in this case, only the new values for `$amount1`).

Comment: Thanks so much it really helped me.